# Is there an analytical solution for the following

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there an analytical solution to this equation:

$A. dM/dt + B. dN/dt = C$

Initial condition,At $t = 0$ ; $M(0) = N(0) = const$

$A,B,C$ are constants and $M(t)$ and $N(t)$.

Comment: What do you mean by A.$dM$

Comment: A and B are constants but A not equal to B

Comment: If M and N are constants than the derivatives is zero

Comment: Speaking generally, to determine two functions you need two differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

$$A. dM/dt + B. dN/dt = C$$
If $A,B,C$ are constants:
$$A. dM + B. dN = Cdt$$
Integrate:
$$AM+BN=Ct+K$$
Where $K$ is a constant $(K=AM(0)+BN(0))$. You have a relation between $M$ and $N$ but you need more information if you need $M$ or $N$ as a function only of the variable $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write as

$$\frac {d(AM+BN)}{dt}=C$$

and you have the solution (only available in terms of $AM+BN$).